# Почему через оператор spread функция работает а через split() нет?

Tags: javascript

```js
let roms = /[^IVX1-9+*\/-\s]/g

const strValidation = str => {
  //  [ 'k', index: 4, input: 'X + k', groups: undefined ]
  console.log(...str.matchAll(roms)); 
  //  str.split(...).matchAll is not a function
  console.log(str.split('').matchAll(roms)); 
}

strValidation('X + k')
```

Comment: А почему она должна работать через split?

Comment: А чтобы ответить на вопрос, надо открыть доки  по console log и посмотреть что он принимает на вход.. А также понимать что возвращает spread и spli

Comment: Может и не должна, вопрос почему не должна. Если str.split и ...str выдают похожие массивы!?

Comment: Нет, они не выдают похожие массивы. Одна из них вообще не возвращает массив вовсе

Comment: A matchAll работает только со строками? Или с массивами тоже!?